# how to get student rank in exam

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a grading table and in the grading table there are columns of user id, schedule id, class id, in class, grades, time worked, and information (graduated or not).

and this is a script that I tried, I can only display data based on information (graduated or not) and the fastest processing time.

```
$data['rank'] = DB::table('grading')  
    select('grading.id_user','lesson.name_lesson','grading.id_lesson','grading.grade','grading.time_worked','gradinng.information','grading.id','grading.created_at', 'grading.id_class', 'class.name_class')
                        ->join('lesson','grading.id_lesson','=','lesson.id')
                        ->join('schedule','penilaian.id_jadwal','=','schedule.id')
                        ->join('class', 'penilaian.id_class', '=','class.id')
                        ->orderBy('grading.grade','desc')
                        ->orderBy('grading.time_worked', 'asc')
                        ->get();
```

I want to display the ranking of students 1-3 with the criteria for passing the exam and the fastest time to do it. I want to display the class ranking and rank in 1 school. how to display rank 1-3 in this exam, thank you for your help.

This is my grading table
[image]

Comment: If you can give an example of the desired result, it might be helpful

Comment: I think you have to write `Where` conditions on the specific columns in your query, like `where('gradinng.information','=','pass')` and also a condition for the fastest time.

Comment: also how exactly you want the result ? plz elaborate with example